# How to construct spinodal and binodal curves from a molecular simulation?

Tags: monte-carlo, phase-transitions

Pretty much what the title states: what is a procedure to construct a binodal and spinodal curve (temperature against composition)?

I am running an on-lattice polymer solution Monte Carlo simulation with a phase transition in an NVT ensemble and want to generate critical temperature curves (the UCST and LCST). I understand that the binodal is when $\frac{dF}{d\phi} =\mu=0$, but how does one go about doing that?

One method I am considering is keeping track of heat capacity over a range of temperatures, given a concentration. In the event that there is a discontinuity, I will record that temperature and plot it against $\phi$. But is this a reasonable method? Does this work?

Comment: Check out work by Edward Maginn, Carlos Vega, Ivo Nezbeda, David Kofke, Panagiotopoulos etc etc. This link might have something http://kea.princeton.edu/papers/kemer.pdf. https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.465023

Comment: Kofke Notes https://www.eng.buffalo.edu/~kofke/ce530/Lectures/Lecture20/index.htm

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but now that it has been more than 1 year, can you update us please? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Did you figure it out?  Were the comments by @Wesley useful?